# incorrect work gnome terminal

Tags: 12.04, unity, command-line, gnome-terminal

I use at work Ubuntu Desktop 12.04. 80% of the time I spend in the terminal. After switching from the putty on gnome terminal, I was unpleasantly surprised to work with some devices (eg Extereme Summit X650):

gnome terminal:

```
# Module lldp configuration.
Press <SPACE> to continue or <Q> to quit:
```

after press SPACE:

```
# Module lldp configuration.
Press <SPACE> to continue or <Q> to quit:[60;D#

#
# Module msdp configuration.
#
```

putty(Windows and Linux)/konsole

```
# Module lldp configuration.
Press <SPACE> to continue or <Q> to quit:
```

after press SPACE:

```
# Module lldp configuration.
#

#
# Module msdp configuration.
#
```

How to fix the gnome terminal?

Comment: Have you tried typing the command **reset** in Terminal?

Comment: I tried Terminal in many Gnome based distributions - the result is similar.

Answer (score 0):

It took awhile to understand your question.

This quote of Bill Hedberg from [comp.terminals](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.terminals/qwhgIz8GhYY) helped me.

> The WY60 is an "ASCII terminal", which means that it responds to
>   "ASCII" control sequences of the form  "Esc~;"  The VT100 is an "ANSI
>   terminal", which means it responds to ANSI control sequences of the
>   form  "Esc[0m"

From your results the [60;D# is the code used to clear the current line that is not being understood. Though ~ is [ascii 126](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii) and [ is ascii 91 I don't see exactly how it applies yet. It may matter somehow in octal or hex.

I think the problem is related to WY60 vs. VT100 [emulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) software involved on both sides. In each case check what is set in your $TERM variable and associated entries in /etc/{termcap|terminfo}. Once you find the cause of the problem a solution like [wy60](https://code.google.com/p/wy60/) might apply.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_Wyse

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in gnome-terminal (well, actually vte). I don't have a fix for it right away, but I've forwarded the report upstream to keep track of it: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748144